# CSS BG&Border Animations on Gradient Button

Tags: css, hover, css-animations, gradient

## What I want:

The hover animation on my button should create a border. After the color ended up at the 4 corners it should draw the border on each side of the button with that gradient color. 
My guess would be to simply add a border which doesn't disappear when hovered on the button but I already have some borders to create that effect so I dont know where to add it.

### My Code:

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;}
#container{
  width:715px;
  height:230px;
  margin:50px auto;
}


.button-8{
  width:140px;
  height:50px;
  border-width:0px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #9357cc 0%,#2989d8 50%,#2cc99d 100%);
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0 0 40px 50px;
}
.button-8 a{
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:16px;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  line-height:50px;
  transition:all .5s ease;
  z-index:2;
  position:relative;
}
.eff-8{
  width:140px;
  height:50px;
  border-width:140px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #9357cc 0%,#2989d8 50%,#2cc99d 100%);
  position:absolute;
  transition:all .5s ease;
  z-index:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.button-8:hover .eff-8{
  border-width:0px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #9357cc 0%,#2989d8 50%,#2cc99d 100%);
}
.button-8:hover a{
  color:#34495e;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">


  <div class="button-8">
    <div class="eff-8"></div>
    <a href="#"> Hover Me </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/css_stroller/yrLm8vgk/

#### Side effects/Notes:

Another problem here is that the text is white and appears to be fading out when mouse leaves the button but I want the text to appear **at the same time** as the gradient background, not before so that it doesnt seem to fade out for a short period of time.

Note: Sometimes the animation is faulty. It is supposed to work like this:
The background slices up in 4 parts in the center and move towards the 4 corners leaving a white background. You might try to hover multiple times, or change z-index. I really dont know why that is.

Comment: Try to use `keyframes` for your requirement. Hope that will work for you.

Comment: I'll have a look thanks